# Extracting content from html tags

Tags: html, extract

I have a directory containing over 100 html files. I need to extract only the contents inside `<TITLE></TITLE>` and `<BODY></BODY>` tags and then format them as:

TITLE, "BODY CONTENT" (That is one line per document)

It would be be beneficial if results from each file in the array can be written to 1 giant text file. I have found following command to format the document to one line:

> `grep '^[^<]' test.txt | tr -d '\n' > test.txt`

Although no specific programming language is preferred, the following will be helpful if i need to modify it further: perl, shell(.sh), sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something in Ruby using Nokogiri.

```
require 'rubygems' # This line isn't needed on Ruby 1.9
require 'nokogiri'

ARGV.each do |input_filename|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(input_filename))
  title, body = doc.title, doc.xpath('//body').inner_text
  puts %Q(#{title}, "#{body}")
end
```

Save that to a `.rb` file, for example `extractor.rb`. Then you need to make sure Nokogiri is installed by running `gem install nokogiri`.

Use this script like so:

```
ruby extractor.rb /path/to/yourhtmlfiles/*.html > out.txt
```

Note that I don't handle newlines in this script, but you seem to have that figured out.

**UPDATE:**

This time it strips newlines and beginning/ending spaces.

```
require 'rubygems' # This line isn't needed on Ruby 1.9
require 'nokogiri'

ARGV.each do |input_filename|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(input_filename))
  title, body = doc.title, doc.xpath('//body').inner_text.gsub("\n", '').strip
  puts %Q(#{title}, "#{body}")
end
```

Comment: Thank you this is extremely close. Its only missing minor formatting, how would i make result from each file in One line (format the each result one per line). For example applying `grep '^[^<]' test.txt | tr -d '\n' > test.txt` to a particular file makes it one line.

Comment: I have tried with multiple files, i might not be clear in explaining. the html files (<body>) are mostly formatted as paragraphs, the script is extracting the <title> and <body> as they appear but does not reformat the text to appear each document in one line in the form: title, "content" . it appears as follows:     TITLE1, "xxxxxxx <break>xxxxxx<break>xxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                  TITLE2,                                                             "xxxxxx<break>x"                      instead of                                                           TITLE1,"xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: Maybe you could pastebin a practical example of input and output?

Comment: Never sir i replied before you update the script, or completed missed it. It works perfectly. Thank you for saving me hours of doing it manually..lol

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with C# and LINQ. A quick example of loading a file:

```
    IDictionary<string, string> parsed = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach ( string file in Directory.GetFiles( @"your directory here" ) )
    {
        var html = XDocument.Load( "file path here" ).Element( "html" );

        string title = html.Element( "title" ).Value;
        string body = html.Element( "body" ).Value;
        body = XElement.Parse( body ).ToString( SaveOptions.DisableFormatting );

        parsed.Add( title, body );
    }

    using ( StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter( @"your file path") )
    {
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in parsed )
        {
            file.WriteLine( string.Format( "{0}, \"{1}\"", pair.Key, pair.Value ) );
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested this particular chunk of code, but it should work. HTH.

**EDIT:** If you have the base directory path, you can use [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to retrieve the file names in the directory.

Comment: thanks, but the code seems a little short. How would i write the results to 1 file? sorry i have no experience with C

Comment: @user1290757 Give me a minute to create a better example, but in the meanwhile, maybe this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Thank you, i have never used C. Here is what i tried          `foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"))
            {
                var html = XDocument.Load("test").Element("html");

                string title = html.Element("title").Value;
                string body = html.Element("body").Value;
                body = XElement.Parse(body).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

                parsed.Add(title, body);
            }

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\"))` I get 4 errors 1: The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Error 3 The type or namespace name 'StreamWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Program.cs 27 20 LINQConsoleApplication1
Error 4 The type or namespace name 'StreamWriter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Program.cs 27 44 LINQConsoleApplication1

Comment: `StreamWriter` needs to reference `System.IO`, `IDictionary` and `Dictionary` need `System.Collections.Generic`, and `XDocument` needs `System.Xml.Linq`. The easiest fix is to add them as `using` references to the top of the file.